# How can I specify the plot range of a BoxWhiskerChart?

Tags: plotting, syntax, charts

I am combining multiple `BoxWhiskerCharts` using `GraphicsGrid`. This works properly, however I want the different charts to have the same y-axis for enabling an easy comparison of the data sets.

How can I specify the range of a `BoxWhiskerChart`? `PlotRange` doesn't work, and I can't find a corresponding command for this kind of chart.

My current code is

```
P1 = BoxWhiskerChart[{DataA, DataB}, 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"A", "B"}, Above]}]

P2 = BoxWhiskerChart[{DataC, DataD}, 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"C", "D"}, Above]}]

GraphicsGrid[{{P1, P2}}]
```

I am thankful for any tips!

Comment: Which Version of *Mathematica* are you using?

Answer (score 3):

I can't see your problem. [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) in Version 10.4.1 **does work fine** for [`BoxWhiskerChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoxWhiskerChart.html) (as it should):

```
d1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 3], 100];
d2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 1], 100];
d3 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[-5, 3], 100];
d4 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[-10, 1], 100];

P1 = BoxWhiskerChart[ {d1, d2}, 
    ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"A", "B"}, Above]}, 
    PlotRange -> {All, {-20, 30}}
];

P2 = BoxWhiskerChart[{d3, d4}, 
    ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"C", "D"}, Above]}, 
    PlotRange -> {All, {-20, 30}}
];

GraphicsGrid[{{P1, P2}}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: BoxWhiskerSameScale]

Answer (score 2):

```
{DataA, DataB, DataC, DataD} = 10 + RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {4, 100}]; 
P1 = BoxWhiskerChart[{DataA, DataB}, ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"A", "B"}, Above]}];
P2 = BoxWhiskerChart[{DataC, DataD}, ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"C", "D"}, Above]}];

GraphicsGrid[{Show[#, PlotRange -> {0, 20}] & /@ {P1, P2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note: Re *PlotRange doesn't work*, it does in Version 9.0.1:

```
BoxWhiskerChart[{DataA, DataB}, ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"A", "B"}, Above]}, 
                PlotRange -> {0, 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice solution, but it somehow assumes that the OP's hypothesis *"`PlotRange`does not work for `BoxWhiskerChart`"* is *true* when it isn't.

Comment: @gwr, just added a note on "_doesn't work_".